# Cloning a tensorflow model, and freezing the clone while original keeps training

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have some class A such that it has:

0) a tensorflow model

1) a train method to train run the graph and train my model

2) a saver which uses [save and restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver)

3) predict method

4) some attributes external to the model

---

Some pseudocode

```
A.sess = tf.Session()
iteration = 0
while True:
    A.train(data)

    if iteration % 50000:
        A.saver.save(path)  # might be relevant? Maybe not to this question
        # help here as detailed below? 
        b_sess = tf.Session()
        B = some_copy_method(A)
        B.sess = b_sess

        threads = []
        for thread in threads:
            # thread B
```

I want to achieve the following:

Copy A, assign it to B, and freeze the model in B such that A can keep training while B can be used as our 'next best' model

---

Questions:

1) Do I need to create a new graph session for B? Will I need to create a new graph session for every thread I spawn?

2) If I used tf.train.restore to 'copy' A to B, will the attributes external to my model be restored?